# How to import OSM polygons data from PostGIS to R?

Tags: r, postgresql, postgis, spatial, ogr

I am new to the world of spatial analysis using R. Using [this](http://download.geofabrik.de/) link I have downloaded OSM data in .osm.pbf format. Then I used [osm2pgsql](http://learnosm.org/en/osm-data/osm2pgsql/) tool to get data in PostgreSQL (PostGIS extension). Now I have several tables in my database and I want to access the polygons table in R and then perform spatial analysis on the polygon vector data. I have been searching around allot but am not able to import required data in R. I found [this](http://conference.scipy.org/scipy2013/tutorial_detail.php?id=110) tutorial quite similar to what I am looking for but its in Python. I want to access polygon data from PostGIS using R.

Therefore, essentially I would like to know interaction of R with PostGIS. Can anybody recommend me any book on this topic? Since I couldn't find a blog or tutorial so far that works for me on my Windows 10 64-bit machine.

Thanks for your time and looking forward for the suggestions.

Comment: really broad question, but this https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html could help you started

Comment: @MLavoie What I found so far is that the problem is with rgdal, I have to configure it in a way that it interacts with postgis. If you have any idea it would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: maybe this https://geospatial.commons.gc.cuny.edu/2014/01/14/load-postgis-geometries-in-r-without-rgdal/

Comment: Thanks MLavoie, using this link I am able to get the table in R but I have to construct SpatialPolygon out of it. This is hectic because of the format of the table I have. But if I use rgdal it would be allot easier as mentioned here:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64950/working-with-postgis-data-in-r

Comment: But since my OS is Windows 10 (64-bit), rgdal doesn't come with implicit driver support for postgis. I am working on it and will post the complete solution. Thanks for the time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have still not found a way to get required data form PostGIS using rgdal package available in R. Probably it is because of my OS issues. (I am not exactly sure as I am not an expert). But I have found an alternative to rgdal and it has done exactly what I wanted it to do. The code is as following:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(rgeos)
library(sp)

# Load data from the PostGIS server
conn = dbConnect(
  dbDriver("PostgreSQL"), dbname="dbNAME", host="localhost", port=5432, 
  user="username", password="pw"
)

strSQL = "SELECT osm_id, name, area, highway, railway, place, ST_AsText(way) AS wkt_geometry FROM table"
df = dbGetQuery(conn, strSQL)

#Geomtery column as R list
geo_col = df$wkt_geometry

polygon_list = suppressWarnings(lapply(geo_col, function(x){
x <- gsub("POLYGON\\(\\(", "", x)
x <- gsub("\\)", "", x)
x <- strsplit(x, ",")[[1]]

#Now each polygon has been parsed by removing POLYGON(( from the start and )) from the end
#Now for each POLYGON its xValues and yValues are to be extracted to for Polygon object
xy <- strsplit(x, " ")

v_xy = suppressWarnings(sapply(xy, function(p){        
  xValue = p[1]
  yValue = p[2]
  vec = c(xValue, yValue)
}))

#Now we have all x values in first column of v_xy and all y values in second column of v_xy
#Let us make the Polygon object now
p_xvalues = as.numeric(v_xy[1, ])
p_yvalues = as.numeric(v_xy[2, ])
p_object <- Polygon(cbind(p_xvalues, p_yvalues))      
}))

#Now we have all of the polygons in polygon object format
#Let us join it with main data frame, i.e. df
df$object_polygon <- polygon_list
#View(df)

#Now Let us form SpatialPolygons() object out of it
Ps_list = list()
for (i in seq(nrow(df))) {
  Ps_list[[i]] <- Polygons(polygon_list[i], ID=df[i,][1])
}
SPs = SpatialPolygons(Ps_list)

#Now FINALY its the time to form SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
row.names(df) = df$osm_id
SPDF = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(Sr = SPs, data = df[, 1:6], match.ID = TRUE)
```

Therefore, essentially I had to write a parser to get the required data which readOGR() does it one line.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know R, but very familiar with postgis. Postgis is just SQL functions, if you can use `Select` you can access postgis,

So if you want access polygon just create new function in postgres.

But if you want display polygons you need check with R what function are available, i usually use `Openlayer` javascript api to show my results in the webpage.

Comment: Yes I know Leaflet and OpenLayers3 very well, but my current issue is to connect to postgis from R, probably using rgdal. Thanks for your time.

Comment: but what you mean `connect to postgis` ? why is different to connect to postgresql?

Comment: because I have geometric (polygon) data, so I mentioned postgis. I can connect to postgres using sqldf or RPostgreSQL. But for spatial data I have to configure rgdal!

Comment: I see, well again Im not familiar with `R` and not sure if they have a way to receive geomety objects. But you can alway return the geometry object as a string instead, using [ST_AsText](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_AsText.html) postgis function. That way you pass that string to Leaflet or Openlayer and let them handle the geometic part and your comunication is just like any postgres `SELECT`

Comment: Yes I am working on it and will post complete solution as I find it. Thanks for your time bro :)